# Tag images in the image itself? HOW-TO

Tags: javascript, image, tags

How to tag images in the image itself in a web page?

I know [Taggify](http://www.taggify.net/), but... is there other options?

[Orkut](http://en.blog.orkut.com/2008/06/tag-thats-me.html) also does it to tag people faces... How is it done?

Anyone knows any public framework that is able to do it?

See a sample bellow from Taggify:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I never know that was called 'tagging'.  It seems like a very confusing overloaded meaning.  (You can also tag images 'in the image itself' by using the EXIF/IPTC standards to add textual tags like "face" to an image.)

Comment: Another update. This looks very nice: http://karlmendes.com/2010/07/jquery-photo-tag-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't javascript but C# 3.0 has an API for doing this. The **System.Windows.Media.Imaging** namespace has a class called **BitmapMetadata** which can be used to read and write image metadata (which is stored in the image itself). Here is a method for retrieving the metadata for an image given a file path:

```
public static BitmapMetadata GetMetaData(string path)
{
    using (Stream s = new System.IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(s, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
        var frame = decoder.Frames.FirstOrDefault();
        if (frame != null)
        {
            return frame.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The BitmapMetadata class has a property for tags as well as other common image metadata. To save metadata back to the image, you can use the [InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.inplacebitmapmetadatawriter.aspx).

Comment: Nice... but I'm kind of looking for something ready-to-use. This solution would require a lot effort in displaying the meta-data in the web page, like in the one above (Taggify Sample)

Answer (score 3):

There's a map tag in HTML that could be used in conjunction with Javascript to 'tag' different parts of an image.

You can see the details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp).

Answer (score 3):

I will re-activate this question and help a bit. Currently the only thing i have found about is http://www.sanisoft.com/downloads/imgnotes-0.2/example.html . A jQuery tagging implementation. If anyone knows about another way please tell us.

;)

Comment: That site seems to have been partially tear down.  The software is [imgNotes](https://plugins.jquery.com/imgNotes/) (a [jQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/)).  I found a demo [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Adding-Notes-Markers-To-An-Image-imgNotes/examples/).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Image.InfoCards (IIC) at http://www.imageinfocards.com . With the IIC meta-data utilities you can add meta-data in very user-friendly groups called "cards".

The supplied utilities (including a Java applet) allow you to tag GIF's, JPEG's and PNG's without changing them visually.

IIC is presently proprietary but there are plans to make it an open protocol in Q1 2009.

The difference between IIC and others like IPTC/DIG35/DublinCore/etc is that it is much more consumer-centric and doesn't require a CS degree to understand and use it...